# How to add action button row wise in a kendo grid in angular 4

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am unable to add button in kendo-grid in angular4 [Screenshot of grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdAb5.png)
Is there any other way to add button?

```
<kendo-grid
    [data]="view | async"
    [pageSize]="state.take"
    [skip]="state.skip"
    [sort]="state.sort"
    [sortable]="true"
    [pageable]="true"
    [scrollable]="'none'"
    [filterable]="false"
    (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
    > 
    <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" width="120">
         <button kendoButton >Default</button>
    </kendo-grid-column>               
    <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="NAME" width="200"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="wef" title="WEF" width="200"></kendo-grid-column>

</kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

To show a button (or any other custom content) within a cell, you need to nest a `ng-template` with the `kendoGridCellTemplate` directive inside a `kendo-grid-column`. ([Documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/templates/#toc-cell-template))

**Example:** ([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vFa3QjLB3fr1nEqfX0Ik?p=preview))

```
<kendo-grid
     ...
>
     <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" width="120">
         <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate>
             <button kendoButton>Default</button>
         </ng-template>
     </kendo-grid-column> 

     ...
</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it woks fine but now I am unable to add kendo dropdown instead of button.

Comment: @Tusharkharat do you get any errors? Maybe you can create a plunker/stackblitz demo? We are also using dropdowns-inside the grid and it works fine.

Comment: @Philip- please check plunker  [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/OCqfVQbf1WZqS5BLJrk5?p=info)

Comment: You need to import `ButtonsModule`in your AppModule. https://plnkr.co/edit/qRMgD58vKV2Y29DlFha7?p=preview

Comment: @Philip- Thanks. How can I give routerLink to edit in that dropdown list for each row?

Comment: I've not worked with the dropdown-buttons so far, but usually kendo is on top with providing the option to customize your stuff with templates.

Comment: Ok. How can I use kendo checkbox for selecting all rows in pagination.

Comment: Have a look at their documentation regarding to selection: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/#toc-selection. If you cannot manage to get that working, I'd suggest to create a new question.